# Unexpected EOF while looking for matching '`', but only when run from makefile?

Tags: c, bash, shell, makefile

My shell script is having an issue, however, it's a bit too long to post here. Here is a link to it: http://pastebin.com/jh9fHJ2e

Does anyone have any idea why I would be getting these two errors? I'm calling it from a makefile like so:

```
.PHONY: compile clean
compile:
    $(shell ./compile.sh)
clean:
    $(shell ./clean.sh)
```

However, if I run it manually (`` `./compile.sh` ``), I do not get the error. What am I doing wrong? I worry that the quotes are coming from the output lines: `make: Nothing to be done for 'default.` due to the weird quote lapse in there, but how do I prevent that if Make is what's causing it?

Hopefully this is a reasonable, non-duplicate question. It's not the same as other similar ones as I've checked. I'm happy to remove if it's a bad question, please simply let me know.

Comment: On the contrary: you pinpointed the problem exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `$(shell ...)` here.  The shell function is like backticks in a shell script: the result of the execution is the standard output of the command invoked.  If your command prints some text, that will try to be executed as a shell script.

A recipe is *already* run in a shell, so you don't need the shell function:

```
.PHONY: compile clean
compile:
        ./compile.sh
clean:
        ./clean.sh
```

I wish I could understand why so many people try to use the shell function in recipes like this... I feel like there must be some "intro to make" out there using very bad examples.

Generally you wouldn't create separate shell scripts, anyway: you'd put the compile and clean commands right into the recipe.  What's the point of having a makefile where you type "make clean" when all it does is run a shell script, so you could just type "./clean.sh" instead and get the same behavior?

Comment: Thanks, this works great! I just got hired on as an undergrad RA about a month ago and some of this code is a real mess - I don't know bash scripting as much as I should and so I tend to miss simple stuff like this. Thanks so much. In 9 minutes when I can mark an answer, I will mark this.

Comment: PS - Why would anyone even try to do this? You're absolutely right that it's already run from the shell... I can't think of a valid reasoning behind this. Maybe you'd have an idea as to why.

Comment: Nope... no idea.  Wish I did so we could try to counteract it :)

Answer (score 1):

The make syntax `$(shell ... )` runs a shell command and substitutes the output of the shell command into the make script at that point.  So when you have a rule like

```
compile:
        $(shell ./compile.sh)
```

it will run the script `compile.sh` and take the output of that shell script as the actions (shell commands) to run to complete the `compile` target.  Since it looks like your `compile.sh` script does the actual compile, outputting messages about what it is doing, when make then tries to run those messages as shell commands, the shell barfs (giving you error messages).